# How to avoid invitations from my own calendars in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I have added a separate calendar (not separate account) in Google Calendar to manage children's events.

Now, when I create an event there, sometimes (didn't completely determine the conditions) I receive an invitation to this very account. It makes very little sense, it's this account's calendar and my own event. It's very inconvenient, as I have to accept each on a few Apple clients.

I'm looking at "Google calendar settings - Settings for my calendars - "Children" - Share with specific people". I can control who receives invitations, but I surely cannot remove myself.

Can I disable the invitations to myself somehow?

Comment: Did you share this calendar with another account in your Apple clients? I think the Google calendar doesn't invite the own account to an event. (as I can't comment yet I posted an answer)

Comment: I did. Let me test and report back.